# Laravel relationship storing to pivot null

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 tables called games, products, game_product. And game_product is my pivot table

This is the structure.

| id | game_id | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |

30 Minutes ago I can attach the game_id and product_id correctly, then i changed nothing. And after I tried to create a new data, its give me this error message

```
Call to a member function games() on null
```

This is my model relationship

**App\Models\Game.php :**

```
public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Product', 'game_product', 'product_id', 'game_id');
    }
```

**App\Models\Product.php :**

```
public function games()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Game', 'game_product', 'game_id', 'product_id'  );
```

And this is my create controller

```
public function productsNew(Request $request, $id)
    {   
        $products = Product::find($id);
        
        $new = Product::create([
            'product_sku' => $request->product_sku,
            'name' => $request->name,
            'seller_price' => $request->seller_price,
            'price' => $request->price,
            'profit' => $request->price - $request->seller_price,
        ]);

        $products->games()->attach($id);
        $new->save();

        
        notify("Product added successfully!", "", "success");
        return redirect('admin/products/'.$id);
    }
    }
```

I try to post the id of game and product to pivot table game_id and product_id. What should I do to store the ID only without any other of value?

Comment: The message says that `$products` is null. It's not clear what you're trying to do here. `$id` seems to be the `Product` identifier you are looking for and then you are trying to attach it as a related game to itself. I would have thought you needed to use `$new`

Comment: I tried to store id game and product after I declare create products function and store it on my pivot table as id of each table, anything wrong in my code?

Comment: You have `$products = Product::find($id);` and then `$products->games()->attach($id);`. What is the purpose of this?

Comment: I wanted to attach Product ID as my URL to the Pivot table

Comment: That product id does not exist. You also need to attach a game to the product not a product.

Comment: Just deleted the `$products = Product::find($id);` and change `$products->games()->attach($id);` to `$new->games()->attach($id);` somehow it works. Thanks before!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the order of

```
$products->games()->attach($id);
$new->save();
```

to be

```
$new->save();
$products->games()->attach($id);
```

As a side note, you are creating a product. Just 1 product. So the variable name mustn't be pluralized as it is singular. `$product`

One final thing, if this function is just part of the CRUD, please follow the convention of naming functions to be: `create/store/show/edit/update/destroy`, makes your and everyone else's lives easier when asking questions.